# Genetate specific version of ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd

Hello friends this command :

```
sencha generate workspace -ext extjs-workspace
```

this generates newest version of ext
which is beta version
and i don't want this i need stable version of extjs 5
How can i do this? 
there is no information about this.

Comment: It's there on the workspace page: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/workspaces.html

Answer (score 0):

The -ext flag downloads the latest version of the framework from the Sencha servers. If you omit that flag it'll generate an empty workspace and you can create an app inside it using:

```
sencha -sdk <path-to-downloaded-sdk> generate app MyApp ./my-app
```

Where `<path-to-downloaded-sdk>` is the directory of the Ext JS SDK you've previously downloaded. You can also specify the SDK at the workspace level:

```
sencha -sdk <path-to-downloaded-sdk> generate workspace ./my-workspace
```